# Take action when closing a Stage in another JavaFX Window

Tags: javafx

When I use Java Swing, I can open a second Window with JDialog, and update a public variable, to do a search, and update data in the Window that was called, using the Try / Finally clause.

That is, I open a second window, and when I close, execute something in finally.

In JavaFX, when I start the Stage, finally is executed right afterwards, not when the window is closed.

How could I solve this? Wait to close the second window, to perform an action?

I thank you for your attention.

```
public void abreTelaStatus(javafx.event.ActionEvent event){
        try {
            try{
                Stage stageSt     = new Stage();
                Parent rootStatus = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Visao/Status.fxml"));
                Scene sceneStatus = new Scene(rootStatus);        

                sceneStatus.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent t) -> {
                    if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                        stageSt.close();
                    }
                });

                stageSt.setScene(sceneStatus);
                stageSt.setTitle("Cadastro de Status");
                stageSt.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
                stageSt.initOwner(((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
                stageSt.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
                stageSt.show();
            } finally{
                System.out.println("Finally - Cod. Status: " + UtilVar.sCodigo);
                //Execute action...
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            MsgAlert.msgBox(null, "Erro ao Criar Tela Cadastro de Status - Erro:: " + ex.getMessage(), "Alerta");
        }
    }
```

Print part of the screen to try to better illustrate

[image]

Second Call Screen
[image]

Call screen, after updating data
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two options:

Use [`showAndWait()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Stage.html#showAndWait()), which waits for the window to close before proceeding:

```
try{
    Stage stageSt     = new Stage();
    Parent rootStatus = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Visao/Status.fxml"));
    Scene sceneStatus = new Scene(rootStatus);        

    sceneStatus.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent t) -> {
        if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
            stageSt.close();
        }
    });

    stageSt.setScene(sceneStatus);
    stageSt.setTitle("Cadastro de Status");
    stageSt.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    stageSt.initOwner(((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
    stageSt.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    // stageSt.show();
    stageSt.showAndWait();
} finally{
    System.out.println("Finally - Cod. Status: " + UtilVar.sCodigo);
    //Execute action...
}
```

I'm not convinced that there's a need for a `try-finally` here, as there's no opportunity for exiting the code block between calling `show()` (or `showAndWait()`) and executing the code currently in the `finally` block (but maybe you are doing something else in your real application).

Alternatively, you can register a handler for the [`onHidden`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.graphics/javafx/stage/Window.html#onHiddenProperty) event, and execute your code there:

```
public void abreTelaStatus(javafx.event.ActionEvent event){
    try {

        Stage stageSt     = new Stage();
        Parent rootStatus = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/Visao/Status.fxml"));
        Scene sceneStatus = new Scene(rootStatus);        

        sceneStatus.addEventHandler(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, (KeyEvent t) -> {
            if (t.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE) {
                stageSt.close();
            }
        });

        stageSt.setScene(sceneStatus);
        stageSt.setTitle("Cadastro de Status");
        stageSt.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
        stageSt.initOwner(((Node)event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow());
        stageSt.initStyle(StageStyle.UTILITY);
        stageSt.setOnHidden(e -> {
            System.out.println("Finally - Cod. Status: " + UtilVar.sCodigo);
            //Execute action...
        });
        stageSt.show();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        MsgAlert.msgBox(null, "Erro ao Criar Tela Cadastro de Status - Erro:: " + ex.getMessage(), "Alerta");
    }
}
```

You can also consider using the [`Dialog` API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/14/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Dialog.html), which has functionality for returning data from showing the dialog.

Comment: hummm ... i use dialog as you mentioned, just to show validation messages, not from a query screen, with loading data ... thanks for the tip, i will research about it.

Comment: I managed to solve ... as the window was already in Modal, it was enough to replace

 //stageSt.show();
  stageSt.showAndWait();

Thank you!

Comment: @JoséAparecido That's the first suggestion in my answer... It doesn't actually need to be modal for that to work.

Comment: I hadn't seen the answer, just comment ... Thanks for the tip, thanks!